# How do you copy part of a string and print it out

Tags: arrays, string

I am pretty new at coding and trying to figure out on how to take a part of a string and print out that part in a function.

For example: Hello

result: llo

Comment: You need to learn the basics of string manipulation in some language.

Comment: Search for "substring". This question will likely be closed without more details, what have you tried etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using
String str = "hello";
System.out.println(str.substring(2));
It will leave the first characters and print the rest. 
Similary you can use the substring() function with the syntax
Substring(startIndex, endIndex) where start index is inclusive and end index is exclusive.